# Математические вычисления в Python

Tags: python

Объясните пожалуйста концепцию вычисления следующих примеров.
Почему `(1905 % 100 != 0)` добавляет `1` к `1905 // 100`?

```
print(1900 // 100 + (1900 % 100 != 0))
print(1905 // 100 + (1905 % 100 != 0))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Потому что внутренне представление `True` -> `1`, а `False` -> `0`.

Конструкция:

```
1905 // 100 + (1905 % 100 != 0)
```

равносильна (согласно [таблице приоритетов операций](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence)):

```
19 + True    #  19 + 1
```

---

Примеры:

```
In [121]: (1900 % 100 != 0)
Out[121]: False

In [122]: (1905 % 100 != 0)
Out[122]: True

In [123]: (1905 % 100 != 0) + 10
Out[123]: 11
```

---

```
In [124]: True * 7
Out[124]: 7
```

Comment: Спасибо) Теперь понял)